# How to zip folders that are newly created in Python program?

Tags: python, zip

I have a program that put all files in different folders, e.g. these files:

```
    20120809_1204567_cat_pic1.jpg
    20120810_1204567_cat_pic1.jpg 
    20120811_1204567_cat_pic1.jpg
```

The program creates 3 different folders with the name of the first number and a subfolder with the name cat. Now I want to zip these folders, but I don't know the name of each folder before I start the program. How could I zip the folders immediately after the creation of these folders?

```
import zipfile
import glob
import datetime
import os 
from collections import defaultdict
from shutil import copyfile

src = 'D:/Testing/src/'

for name in glob.glob('D:/Testing/src/*'):  
print name

dict_date = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
for fil in os.listdir(src):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src, fil)):
        date, animal = fil.split('_')[0], fil.split('_')[2]
        dict_date[date][animal].append(fil)

for date in dict_date:
    for animal in dict_date[date]:
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(src, date, animal))
        except os.error:
            pass
        for fil in dict_date[date][animal]:
            copyfile(os.path.join(src, fil), os.path.join(src, date, animal, fil))



directory = src
os.chdir(directory)
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
for filename in files:
    os.unlink(filename)

files2 = glob.glob('*.png')
for filename in files2:
os.unlink(filename)
```

Comment: have you tried shutil.make_archive()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one zip file per folder:

```
>>> for date in dict_date:
with ZipFile(os.path.join(path, date, '{0}.zip'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:
    for animal in dict_date[date]:
        for fil in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, date, animal)):
            if fil.endswith('.jpg'):
                myzip.write(os.path.join(path, date, animal, fil))
```

This should replace your lines starting from `directory = src`.

Comment: its working but the problem is that all folders are now in one zip file but i need every folder seperated in a zip file and not all in one. and every zip file should get the name of the seperated folder

Comment: now is he zipping the subfolder cat but not the main folder with the date and i need the main folder

Comment: Ah, you mean it went one level too low ? You'd like one zip per date, not one per animal ?

Comment: yes that what i mean. i need the zip file of the folder ( 20120809 ) in the same folder where is unziped file is

Comment: Ok, I changed the directory level.

Comment: what can i do if there are not only jpg´s but rather txt and avi ? but they have all to be in the same zip

Comment: Then just change `if fil.endswith('.jpg'):` by `if not fil.endswith('.zip'):`.

Comment: thanks. is it able to put the directory level one more higher ?

Comment: If you want the zip file to be created one level higher, then use `with ZipFile(os.path.join(path, '{0}.zip'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:`.